# Sanitizing Inputs using Regex and Booleans

Tags: c#

I am using Regex to validate if the email, password, and username input are legitimate. It is not verifying. And users are able to type anything they want and it will go into my database.

I want all the booleans to be true in order to execute //function.

```
    private void bunifuFlatButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string username = textBox1.Text;
        bool IsRealUser = Regex.IsMatch(username, @"\A(?:[A-Za-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[A-Za-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[A-Za-z0-9](?:[A-Za-z0-9-]*[A-Za-z0-9])?\.)+[A-Za-z0-9](?:[A-Za-z0-9-]*[A-Za-z0-9])?)\Z");
        string password = textBox2.Text;
        bool IsRealPass = Regex.IsMatch(password, @"^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d).{8,15}$");
        string email = textBox4.Text;
        bool IsRealEmail = Regex.IsMatch(email, @"^([0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*@([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9})$");

        if (textBox1.Text == "" || textBox2.Text == "" || textBox3.Text == "" || textBox4.Text == "")
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Fill out the required forms!");
            return;
        }
        else if (textBox2.Text != textBox3.Text)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Your passwords are not matching");
        }

        else if (IsRealPass || IsRealUser || IsRealEmail) //I want all these inputs to be true in order to execute //function.
        {
             //function
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As written, if any of the tests are true, the block will be executed.

```
    else if (IsRealPass || IsRealUser || IsRealEmail)
    {
         //function
    }
```

You want `&&` so that all test conditions must be true for the block to be executed.

```
    else if (IsRealPass && IsRealUser && IsRealEmail)
    {
         //function
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! I have been spending a lot of time on this.

Comment: Yes, so you need to use boolean AND `&&`, not boolean OR `||`.  With OR if any single term is true the entire expression is true.

Comment: @OracleStart `||` means OR, `&&` means AND